# .net Maui MediaPicker.CaptureVideoAsync returns null for Android

Tags: c#, maui

I'm trying to use default media capture tool MediaPicker to shoot video on android.
Here's my code:

```
            if (MediaPicker.Default.IsCaptureSupported)
            {
                if (await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>() != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    var result = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
                    if (result != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                    { return; }
                }

                var video = await MediaPicker.CaptureVideoAsync();
                string localFilePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, video.FileName);
            };
```

The camera starts without any problem, i can shoot the video, but when the function CaptureVideoAsync() always returns Fileresult as a null:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLYlg.png)

Works same way for debugging with android emulator (API 33 (Android 13.0) and on a hardware device.

I'm using .net 7 maui project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem in my project. But the same code worked well in the android emulator (API 31 (Android 12.0).

And I have check the source code about the [media picker on the android](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/fe4bc5b8258f4abe037f0d3c3f54de1facfef853/src/Essentials/src/MediaPicker/MediaPicker.android.cs#L49) and fond that it will return null when user cancel the operation about the video capture.

And I also debugged to detect it. The cod will go to the `return null` after I stop the video recording and then get back to my app immediately. But on the android emulator (API 31 (Android 12.0), it will show the buttons about save and cancel operation. If user taps **✔** button, it will return the result.

So this should be a new issue for the `MediaPicker.CaptureVideoAsync()` in the android 13. You can [post a new issue on the github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the above code works well in Maui .Net 8, in Visual Studio 2022 with Android 13 emulator. No nulls are thrown.